# Ruby on Rails: UTF-8 encoding string that has %F1 in content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

I'm struggling to find the right method in Rails that can convert UTF-8 codes to its displayable value.

In my case, it's converting some user input like "John%20Da%F1e" to "John Dañe" if possible.

Currently, i have the following:

```
unescaped_name = CGI::unescape(params[:name]) # this turns "John%20Da%F1e" into "John Da\xF1e"
@q = I18n.transliterate(unescaped_q) #this yields an 'invalid byte sequence in UTF-8' error
```

In essence, i'm trying to go from "John%20Da%F1e" (already encoded in UTF-8) to "John Dañe".

One thing i've tried was

```
.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

but that replaces the ascii (% to \x) to "John Dae".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Ruby what the encoding of the parsed string *should* be. It looks like you are working in Latin-1 to start with ('ISO-8859-1'). There are a few different options. If you want to limit this decision to just the string you are processing, you can use `.force_encoding` like this

```
require 'cgi'
unescaped_name = CGI::unescape( "John%20Da%F1e" ).force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')
#  => "John Da\xF1e"
unescaped_name.encode('UTF-8')
#  => "John Dañe"
```

Note that once the encoding is set up correctly, it *already* contains the correct characters, but you won't necessarily see that until you convert it to an encoding that you can display. So where I show `"John Da\xF1e"` that's only because my terminal is set to display UTF-8 - `\xF1` is the byte for `ñ` in Latin-1 encoding.

---

As far as I can tell, the URI encoding for UTF-8 bytes of the same string in a single step looks like this:

```
"John%20Da%C3%B1e"
CGI::unescape( "John%20Da%C3%B1e" )
#  => "John Dañe"
```

Comment: Hey Neil could you take a look at this ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029367/before-action-on-import-from-csv