# Before Action on Import from CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, import, character-encoding

I have a simple CSV import where the provided file is already broken (UTF characters) (German).

e.g.: The list has :

```
G%C3%B6tterbote
```

where as the right name should be

```
Götterbote
```

I'm trying to force the encoding when importing the CSV.

**My Import Action**

```
  def import
    Player.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to players_path, notice: "Players Imported successfully"
  end
```

**My Import Method**

```
  def self.import(file)
    SmarterCSV.process(file.path) do |row|
      Player.create(row.first)
    end
  end
```

I found out that this converts the String successfully, but couldn't implement it successfully:

```
 u = "G%C3%B6tterbote"
   => "G%C3%B6tterbote" 

 u1 = CGI::unescape(u).force_encoding('UTF-8')
    => "Götterbote"
```

So basically i need something like a `before_action` (i guess)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a before action.

You need a pre-prossessor, well actually you need to pre-prossess yourself.

Your CSV comes with columns. Column 0, 1, 2, 3 etc (since you don't use headers).

So, for your text columns, let's call them for the sake of the example columns 1, 3, 5.

```
def self.import(file)
    text_cols=[1,3,5] #for example
    SmarterCSV.process(file.path) do |row|
        text_cols.each do |column|
            row[column]=CGI::unescape(row[column]).force_encoding('UTF-8')
        end
        Player.create(row)
    end
end
```

Or simply, for your particular case:

```
def self.import(file)
    SmarterCSV.process(file.path) do |row|
        row.first=CGI::unescape(row.first).force_encoding('UTF-8')
        Player.create(row.first)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey Stavros, i'm getting an error, which i'm getting a lot: undefined method `tr' for #<Hash:0x007ffbc170eda0>

Comment: I was just now looking at this -> https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv#example-1c-how-smartercsv-processes-csv-files-as-chunks-and-passes-arrays-of-hashes-to-a-given-block